# Set language manually in Flutter (flutter_localizations)

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I've integrated flutter_localizations to my app and works fine. I want to user to be able to select own preferred language by clicking on button (raised, flat, icon etc.). I could not figured out what to do, I would appreciate any help!

my codes: 
app_localizations.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  //Helper method to keep the code in the widgets concise
  // Localizations are accessed using an InheritedWidget "of" syntax
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  //Static member to have a simple access to the delegate from the MaterialApp
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate = _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  Map<String, String> _localizedString;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    //Load the language JSON file from the "lang" folder
    String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizedString = jsonMap.map((key, value){
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });

    return true;
  }

  //This method will be called from every widget which needs a localized text
  String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedString[key];
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    //Include all of your supported language codes here
    return ['en', 'az', 'tr'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async { 
    //AppLocalizations class is where the JSON loading actually runs
    AppLocaliza

    tions localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
        await localizations.load();
        return localizations;
      }

      @override
      bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
    }
```